# ngModel is not binding select in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form in my application which contains `title`, `price`, `category (select)` and `imagUrl` data. I applied `ngModel` with every field and it's working fine except the `select` element. When I `console.log()` form data I get the value of every field but the value of the select element which is undefined.  I imported the `AngularForms` module in `app.module.ts`

this is my `product-form-component-html` code

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category"  class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key$">
        {{ c.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="imageUrl">image URL</label>
      <input ngModel name="iamgeUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

this is `product-form-component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService, private productService: ProductService ) { 
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(product) {
    console.log(product);
    this.productService.create(product);
  }
}
```

this is `product-service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? please help me with detailed answer

my Firebase Database
[image]

Comment: what is `c.key$`? shouldn't it be `[value]="c.key"`?

Comment: @j4rey actually i am getting data from `firebase` so `c.key$`  key value of database .. let me add database in my Question

Comment: @j4rey yeah , but `[value]="c.$key"` now it is solved 
thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer    `[value]="c.$key"` 
. I was assigning `[value]="c.key$"` that is why i was getting error.